# Google plus login access token retriew issue

Tags: android, google-plus

I have integrated google plus login in to my android application according to the following link

[google plus andoid integration](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android)

But now I want to retrieve the access token, for that I have created a project in api console and developed a client id for android application,

This is how I retrieve the token. but unfortunately I can't get the token, it recieves null

```
String scopesString = Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PLUS_ME;
String scopes = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + "client id" + ":api_scope:" + scopesString;
```

also there is an exception

```
03-17 15:20:14.338: W/System.err(8084): com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
03-17 15:20:14.338: W/System.err(8084):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
03-17 15:20:14.338: W/System.err(8084):     at com.myapp.exemple.NewInstallation$12.doInBackground(NewInstallation.java:600)
03-17 15:20:14.338: W/System.err(8084):     at com.myapp.exemple.NewInstallation$12.doInBackground(NewInstallation.java:1)
03-17 15:20:14.348: W/System.err(8084):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-17 15:20:14.348: W/System.err(8084):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-17 15:20:14.348: W/System.err(8084):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-17 15:20:14.348: W/System.err(8084):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
03-17 15:20:14.348: W/System.err(8084):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-17 15:20:14.348: W/System.err(8084):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-17 15:20:14.348: W/System.err(8084):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string (presuming "client_id" is replaced with your real client ID) is for retrieving the code for server side offline access, not the access token. This will *always* require the consent dialog to be shown, which is what the recoverable exception being thrown will do if you'd like.

To get the access token you just need the string "oauth2:scope scope" - this will still require a consent dialog if the user has never granted access to your app. I have put an example gist on https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/9607551 - the relevant part:

```
String scopes = "oauth2:profile email";
String token = null;
try {
    token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
} catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
return token;
```

If you do want to retrieve the code, then use the string you were before, but be aware it will require consent every time - so its tricky if you want to sign in both on the client and the server using it. You can use the ID token in order to check with the server whether it already has a refresh token - I wrote a post about that a while back: http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/10/google-android-client-server-sign-in.html - it uses PlusClient rather than GoogleApiClient but it is relatively easy to translate from one to the other.

Comment: thanks for you reply . it worked , i recieved the access token , But i have some questions in my mind , how can we retrieve access token wihout adding client id (android client id in console.) also what do u refer by "oauth2:profile email" .

Comment: it's "oauth2:" followed by a space separated list of the OAuth 2.0 scopes you are requesting - e.g. you could equally have `"oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email"`

Comment: but why dont we have to assign client id in here ??

Comment: The client ID is automatically inferred from the SHA-1 of the signing key and the package name. The client Id in the other call is the client id of the server, not of the android app, as the server needs to do a code exchange to get an access token. Because in this case you're getting an access token directly, you are using the implicit client ID of the Android app - and because access tokens are bearer tokens they can be used straight away.